# How to pass selected Gtk TreeView row to Gtk TreeStore insert function?

Tags: gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to insert a row into a Gtk.TreeStore, for which I have to pass the selected row number from Gtk.TreeView. I found the solution for PyGTK but not for PyGObject.

For PyGTK the insert function looks like this (http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreestore.html#method-gtktreestore--insert):

```
 def insert(parent, position, row=None)
```

The position can be queried like this:

```
 treeview = Gtk.TreeView()
 selection = treeview.get_selection()
 model, iter = selection.get_selected()
 path = iter.get_selected_rows()[0]
 index = path.get_indices()[0]
```

But in PyGObject I get the error:

```
self.index = self.path.get_indices()[0]
AttributeError: 'LayerDataStore' object has no attribute 'get_indices'
```

How can I get the integer value of the row number? Am I approaching the problem in a weird way? It seems like the solution should be simpler and have less code.

### Further Reading:

This is the description of the insert function in GTK3:

- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeStore.html#Gtk.TreeStore.insert

Similar question for PyGTK:

- [Getting the row number of Gtk TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730837/getting-the-row-number-of-gtk-treeview)

Similar question for C++:

- [Get data from selected row of gtk treeview - gtkmm, c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448876/get-data-from-selected-row-of-gtk-treeview-gtkmm-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. But I am not sure if there is a simpler solution:

First call select on the TreeView:

```
tree = Gtk.TreeView()
select = tree.get_selection()
```

*select* is then a **Gtk.TreeSelection**. We use this object to call *get_selected_rows()*:

```
selected_rows = select.get_selected_rows()
```

The function returns a **tuple** of a **LayerDataStore** and a **GtkTreePath** when a row is selected. Otherwise the **GtkTreePath** is an empty list **[]**.

Then assign the **GtkTreePath** to a variable:

```
path = selected_rows[1]
```

Path is now a **list** of the **GtkTreePath** or an empty list **[]** if nothing is selected. You can insert an if-function here to avoid getting any Errors.

We then have to unpack the list by using:

```
row = path[0]
```

Now the variable row is a **TreePath** and the print function will return 0 for the first row, 1 for the second row and so on. For nested trees it will return 0:0 for the first nested object in the first row, 0:1 for the second object in the first row and so on.

With the *get_indices* function we can convert the **TreePath** to a **list**:

```
index = row.get_indices()
```

The print function will now print [0] for the first row and [1] for the second. The nested objects are [0,0] for the first object of the first row and [0,1] for the second nested object of the first row.

Because I am just interested in the row number itself I am using this assignment to get only the row number:

```
row_number = index[0]
```

Finally the row number is passed to the TreeStore:

```
store.insert(None, row_number, [True, "New Layer")])
```

Helpful links:

- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeSelection.html
- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/structs/TreePath.html
- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeView.html
- https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeStore.html